# What is window.Element()?

Tags: javascript, browser

I see the `Element` member on my `window` object (using the developer tools in both Chrome 54 and IE 11). `typeof window.Element` returns `function` yet `Element()` returns `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor(…)` in Chrome.

Moreover, `Object.keys(window).filter(e => e === 'Element').length` returns `0`.

I'm not able to find any reference to `window.Element` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp).

Can anybody tell me what this function is and why it acts weird vis-a-vis the dev tools and Object.keys?

Comment: `document.createElement("foo") instanceof Element; // true`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: `Element` is a IDL-specified interface for HTML elements (https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element) (that is implemented as a constructor/prototype in JavaScript), but it is not specified to be directly constructable.

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).includes("Element"); // true` The `Object.keys()` method does not include non-enumerable properties.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was aware of the Element interface, that is, a definition of the shape of the object returned by createElement as you mention. But I always thought it was just a *specification*, never noticed the concrete implementation (?) on `window`.  Are there other similar members of window?  Why is it not enumerable?  Can anything actually execute it?  What would you expect to break in my browsing experience if I did `window.Element = 'broken'`?

Answer (score 0):

> The Element interface represents an object of a Document. This
>   interface describes methods and properties common to all kinds of
>   elements.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)